# How do I normalize this database to 3nf?

Tags: database, database-normalization

[image]

I'm very confused and not sure what to do with joistcost, floorcost and projecttotal.

joistcost is the cost of an individual component

floorcost is the joist cost multiplied by the width

projecttotal is the cost of all the floors in a project

I'd be very appreciative of any help, I have no idea how to normalize this correctly.

Comment: Well what is your textbook & what does is tell you to do? Please read about homework at How to Ask & google 'stackexhange homework'. Please explain what you are certain about and why & where you are stuck following your textbook & why. Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use an image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what cannot be given in text. Your question shows no understanding at all, so an answer is just a rewrite of your textbook from absolute basics.

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view you don't need to do anything regarding JoistCost. There is a direct relation between this column and tblJoist candidate key from what I understand.

As to the rest, you need to identify candidate keys in your tables and make sure there is a direct relation between the column of your concern and the candidate key itself. If there is indirect relation right now, you need to separate it to a different table, to have the direct one.

Answer (score 0):

You're having trouble normalizing it because storing those subtotals is a denormalized design by definition.

Normalization is about making sure that each piece of information is stored once, and therefore there's no way for values to get out of sync.

Since you store `FloorCost` which should be the product of `Width` * `tblJoist.JoistCost`, there's a risk that if the JoistCost changes, then the FloorCost would be inaccurate. Storing the result of calculations like this conflicts with rules of normalization.

In fact, you have another problem: I would guess that the cost of a joist may change from year to year. So it's not unexpected that the unit cost will change. When you're designing a project database like this, you should **copy** the unit cost when you do the project. That way, it retains the value at the time the project was done, and the unit cost in `tblJoist` can be updated subsequently.

That isn't violating normalization because it becomes different information when you copy the unit cost to tblFloor. It's the unit cost of a joist on the date you did the project. The joist cost in `tblJoist` is the *current* joist cost, which will be different next year.

So I'd design `tblFloor` with columns `Width`, `JoistCost` (copied), and optionally `FloorCost`, which you could keep in sync by using a trigger, or some databases have a feature to make a column auto-calculated based on other columns in the same row (for instance [MySQL's generated columns](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html)).

The `tblProject.ProjectTotal` is a different problem. It's the sum total of all the floors in that project. If you store it in `tblProject` for convenience, this is up to you, but this is technically redundant information because you should also get the same result from:

```
SELECT SUM(FloorCost) FROM tblFloor WHERE ProjectID = ?
```

If that gives a different sum than `tblProject.ProjectTotal` then someone made a mistake. The question is: if you find a discrepancy like this, which is correct?

Denormalization can be worthwhile sometimes, but it carries a risk that data will get out of sync. You have to write application code to keep that from happening.